# Else block not fulfilling my condition

Tags: javascript

```
if(a == 1 || b == 0) {
    document.getElementById("div").style.display = "none";
}
 else {
    document.getElementById("div").style.display = "block";
 }
```

When I select `a value 1` or `b value 0` my div style set to `none` because condition is true, but when I select `a value 2` or `b value 3` means anything except `1` or `0` my div is not showing it's in display: none, it needs to display `block`.

Can you guyz know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to have a value not 1 and b value not 0 to get your else execute.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal I already tried that way same thing happened. Not worked.

Comment: @Rahul a and b are different values coming from different text element can't do with AND operator

Comment: **[Working well for me](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/hwwvsayv/1/)**. Can you replicate the issue in snippet?

Comment: I just tried the if else in the console with the exact same values as provided by you and it did work as expected. with `a = 1` or`b = 0` you enter the if. With `a = 2` and `b = 3` you enter the else... :D

Comment: @DomenikReitzner That's fine once it's goes to display none and again when you select another value except 1 or 0 it is not showing. I am selecting my values from select box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where do you get your a and b from?

Are you sure they are integers and not string?

You could try

```
if(parseInt(a) == 1 || parseInt(b) == 0) {
```

Comment: I am already converting my values using parseInt. My values are coming from select box

Comment: Do you use `<select>` or `<input type="checkbox">`, because you wrote "select box". Is this a new hybrid I don't know about? 

Comment: ;) It's fixed now a and b values are string I forgot to parse my mistake ;)

Comment: can happen. Those little things